# Android app freezes on finishing activity, runOnUiThread() stops working

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity

I'm in the process of writing my first android app, an asteroids clone, and I've got one last bug I can't figure out. The game activity will occasionally freeze when the game ends and tries to go to the game over activity. The game activity has a few UI views that stop working before it freezes. There is a Button to pause the game which stops responding to input. There is also a TextView for the score that I am updating using runOnUIThread() (since I am running the game on a separate thread) which stops updating.

There are a few things that make this puzzling to me. First off, I'm not seeing any error messages. The bug only happens about 1 out of every 5 times the game activity is started and it happens at random points while it is running. It happens when the game activity starts about half the time, but seemingly may occur at any point, although it does tend to happen sooner than later even when it doesn't occur right at the start. Also, the game thread and the custom game View I made keep updating fine when the bug occurs. Finally, I have two virtual joystick Views I made to control the player's motion and shooting which also keep updating and responding to touch input fine. These last two really confuse me because at first I thought the main thread was doing too much work or getting stuck in a loop or something, but if I understand correctly (and according to some tests I've done) drawing and touch input happen on the main thread, and as far as I can tell all views are drawing fine and touch input is working for the joysticks but not the pause button. Also, if the main thread was unresponsive, wouldn't I get an app not responsive popup? That never happens though.

I've tried removing all instances of runOnUIThread() just to see if that fixed it with no effect other than breaking the score TextView and leaving the app stuck in the game activity even when the bug doesn't occur. I've tried printing the names of the threads returned by Thread.currentThread() in the game loop, in the onDraw() method of the game view, in the onTouch() method of JoystickView and when updating the score TextView in the game activity to ensure I actually am running 2 separate threads and everything is running on the threads they should be (game thread for the game loop, main thread for everything else), and that checked out. I've tried cutting down on creating new objects during the game loop, not sure what that would do other than help performance to be honest but I figured it couldn't hurt, also to no effect.

This all makes it difficult for me to know what code to post. Here are some guesses:

The onCreate, goToGameOverActivity, and updateScoreTextView methods from my game activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        gameView = findViewById(R.id.gameView);
        game = new Game(this, gameView);
        float joystickRadius = 150;
        CartesianPoint2D motionJoystickCenter = new CartesianPoint2D(
                10 + joystickRadius,
                Constants.getScreenInformation().getHeight() - 10 - joystickRadius);
        motionJoyStickView = new MotionJoystickView(this, joystickRadius, motionJoystickCenter, game);
        CartesianPoint2D shootJoystickCenter = new CartesianPoint2D(
                Constants.getScreenInformation().getWidth() - 10 - joystickRadius,
                Constants.getScreenInformation().getHeight() - 10 - joystickRadius);
        shootJoystickView = new ShootJoystickView(this, joystickRadius, shootJoystickCenter, game);
        scoreTextView = findViewById(R.id.playActivityScoreTextView);
        pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.playActivityPauseButton);
        soundEffects = new SoundEffects(this);
        game.start();
    }


    public void goToGameOverActivity() {
        game.stop();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void updateScoreTextView(int score) {
        scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        scoreTextView.invalidate();
    }
```

The Runnables I am using to update the score TextView and signal that the game is over using runOnUIThread():

```
package com.group18.spacerocks.play.view;

import com.group18.spacerocks.play.PlayActivity;

public class UpdateScoreTextView implements Runnable {

    protected int newScore;
    protected PlayActivity playActivity;

    public UpdateScoreTextView(int newScore, PlayActivity playActivity) {
        System.out.println("Setting ScoreTextView to " + newScore + ".");
        this.newScore = newScore;
        this.playActivity = playActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        playActivity.updateScoreTextView(newScore);
    }
}

package com.group18.spacerocks.play;

public class GoToGameOverActivity implements Runnable {

    protected PlayActivity playActivity;

    public GoToGameOverActivity(PlayActivity playActivity) {
        this.playActivity = playActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        playActivity.goToGameOverActivity();
    }
}
```

The run() method from the GameThread class extending thread which updates the game:

```
public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (running) {
            while (paused) {
                currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
                try {
                    sleep(1);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
            if (timeSinceLastUpdate >= TARGET_UPDATE_LENGTH) {
                currentUpdateLength = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
                game.update(currentUpdateLength);
                gameView.invalidate();
                lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
                UPS++;
                timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;
                if (currentTime - lastSecondTime >= 1000000000) {
                    System.out.println("UPS: " + UPS);
                    UPS = 0;
                    lastSecondTime = currentTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally the code for my JoystickView class, which has 2 child classes for motion and shooting:

```
package com.group18.spacerocks.play.joystick;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.group18.spacerocks.R;
import com.group18.spacerocks.play.CartesianPoint2D;
import com.group18.spacerocks.play.PlayActivity;
import com.group18.spacerocks.play.Game;

public class JoystickView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    protected boolean inUse;
    protected float radius;
    protected float buttonRadius;
    protected CartesianPoint2D center;
    protected CartesianPoint2D buttonOffset;
    protected PlayActivity playActivity;
    protected Game game;
    protected Paint outlinePaint;
    protected Paint buttonPaint;

    public JoystickView(PlayActivity playActivity, float radius, CartesianPoint2D center, Game game) {
        super(playActivity);
        inUse = false;
        this.radius = radius;
        buttonRadius = radius / 2;
        this.center = center;
        this.buttonOffset = CartesianPoint2D.getInstance();
        this.playActivity = playActivity;
        this.game = game;
        setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) radius * 2, (int) radius * 2));
        setX(center.getX() - radius);
        setY(center.getY() - radius);
        outlinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        outlinePaint.setAlpha(100);
        outlinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        outlinePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        outlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        buttonPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        buttonPaint.setAlpha(100);
        buttonPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        buttonPaint.setColor(playActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.textTitleColor));
        buttonPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = playActivity.findViewById(R.id.playActivityLayout);
        viewGroup.addView(this);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, outlinePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(radius + buttonOffset.getX(), radius + buttonOffset.getY(), buttonRadius, buttonPaint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            inUse = false;
            buttonOffset.setX(0);
            buttonOffset.setY(0);
        }
        else {
            inUse = true;
            CartesianPoint2D motionPosition = new CartesianPoint2D(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            CartesianPoint2D centerOffset = new CartesianPoint2D(motionPosition.getX() - radius, motionPosition.getY() - radius);
            if (centerOffset.getMagnitude() > radius) {
                buttonOffset = CartesianPoint2D.createFromMagnitudeAndDirection(radius, centerOffset.getDirection());
            } else {
                buttonOffset = centerOffset;
            }
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any insight is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for a few days now and I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know exactly what the cause was, but I fixed it by making the game view an extension of SurfaceView so I could draw in a thread other than the main thread.